# Allow user to upload JSON, then use the JSON to render the page

Tags: php, html, json, upload

Currently on my website, I allow users to paste JSON data into an HTML form, then I use the JSON data to alter the rendering of the page. How do I replace the form with a file upload feature? I do not need to store the data on the Web server. As long as it all works within the browser it is okay. My website is written in PHP. Thanks.

Comment: Use `file_get_contents($_FILES['name']['tmp_name'])` where `name` is the name of the `<input type="file">`

Comment: In place of `$_POST['textarea_name']`

Comment: This could all be done in the browser, but how easy that is depends on how the data is structured and how the page is constructed. It would have the advantage that no page reload would be required. Can you post a simple example of both page source and JSON data where this would be applied?

Comment: @Barmar - Is your example using jquery? I am not currently using jquery.

Comment: My comments are PHP, not JavaScript.

Comment: You don't need jQuery. Just add `<input type="file" name="name">` to your form. The user will upload the file using that, and then you use `$_FILES` in PHP to access the uploaded file.

Comment: Does that require a page reload? I want to avoid that if I can. (Though it is not a big deal either way. As long as I don't have to store anything on the Web server.)

Comment: @Tangentially Perpendicular - The page generates a rendering of a PC keyboard. The data stores coordinates, dimensions, labels of each key for various types of keyboards. I can create/destroy DOM objects using JS with no problems. Just need a general idea of how to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple demonstrator that prompts the user for a file, reads it, and posts the content to a `<textarea>`. It also parses the JSON content to a variable and sends that to the `console.log`. From here you should be able to unpack the data and update your page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>File Reader Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="fileForm">
    <input type="file" name="fileItem" id="fileItem" required>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<textarea id="fileContents"></textarea>
<script>
    (function(){
        "use strict";
        // Add an event handler to the form's submit event
        document.getElementById('fileForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
            // Stop the browser submitting anything
            e.preventDefault();
            // Get the file object
            let file = document.getElementById('fileItem').files[0];
            // Check the file is actually JSON
            if (file.type !== "application/json") {
                document.getElementById('fileContents').value = "Invalid file type"+file.type;
            } else {
                // Create a file reader
                let reader = new FileReader();
                // Add an event handler to the 'load' event
                reader.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
                    // Post the file contents to the page
                    document.getElementById('fileContents').value = e.target.result;
                    // parse the JSON
                    let jsonData = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
                    // Process incoming JSON data here.
                    console.log(jsonData);
                })
                // Read the file as text. We'll parse it with JSON.parse later
                reader.readAsText(file);
            }
        })
    })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aha! Wasn't sure if server side scripting was necessary to access the _contents_ of transferred files. Was this capability added to JavaScript at some later date, such as recently?

Comment: According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=FileReader) the FileReader API started appearing in 2010, and was supported by all major browsers by 2012. I'm not sure that qualifies as 'recently'.

Comment: Yes, to me it is recent, LOL!